# Create row in Flexible layout ACF programatically

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am missing something really simple I feel but have looked around and I can't find the answer

```
while ( have_rows('page_builder') ) : the_row();
  if( get_row_layout() == 'one_column' ): // Single Column
    update_sub_field('field_60745782d2943', get_the_content());
  endif;
endwhile;
```

This is inside a loop going through all the posts. I have an ACF Flexible Content set up and inside of it varying layouts. One of them is called One Column. I need to take the_content() from each post and update a sub field inside  the one_column layout. This concept works when One Column has been selected and saved for each post manually. The whole have_rows('page_builder') is never triggered because, well there isn't a row. I have 500+ posts
When adding a new layout type, is that triggering in ACF? Is it adding a new row? Sub row? I have tried every iteration I can find but none of them will create that block for me. Ultimately I'd like to add a chunk of code before this one to get one_column created so this runs right through. I am sure there is actually a way I can just update the sub_field once the row is created but I am struggling just to get it created!

```
if(!have_rows("page_builder")){
    THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK. HOW DO I CREATE AN INSTANCE OF 'ONE COLUMN'
}

SOLUTION

$value = array(
  // nested array for each row you want to create
  array(
    // field key => value pairs for row
    'acf_fc_layout' => 'one_column',
    'field_60745782d2943' => get_the_content();
  )
)
update_field('field_key_of_flex_field', $value, $post_id)

It was the acf_fc_layout that I was missing.
```

Comment: You used `get_the_content`, are you sure you didn't mean to call it as a function `get_the_content()`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: @JeremyHarris I update code to reflect your catch. Thanks!

Comment: Was that the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `add_row()` function

```
if(!have_rows("page_builder")){
     $new_row = array(
        'field_XXXXXX' => 'Your value here', //replace with the appropriate field key
    ); 

    add_row('page_builder', $new_row);
}
```